# How to make a confusion matrix when testing a model on data with only positive cases?

Tags: r, caret, confusion-matrix

I have recently encountered a problem with the function `confusionMatrix` in R from the `caret` package regarding a machine learning procedure. In detail, I have trained a binary classifier with two levels ("Cancer" & "Normal") and I'm trying to test it in independent datasets. However, one of my test datasets had represented only one of the levels regarding the response variable - that is only cancer samples. So,

```
final.classes.xgb.gse <- predict(xgbTune, newdata = test.set.gse)

head(final.classes.xgb.gse)
[1] Cancer Cancer Cancer Cancer Cancer Cancer
Levels: Cancer Normal

table(final.classes.xgb.gse)
final.classes.xgb.gse18088
Cancer Normal 
    51      2
```

and my "true labels"-reference for this dataset factor variable:

```
head(test.labels.gse)
[1] Cancer Cancer Cancer Cancer Cancer Cancer
Levels: Cancer
```

But when I type:

```
confuse.mat.gse18088 <- confusionMatrix(data=final.classes.xgb.gse, test.labels.gse)
**Error in confusionMatrix.default(data = final.classes.xgb.gse, test.labels.gse) : 
  the data cannot have more levels than the reference**
```

Is there a way to solve this ? As this test dataset has only samples belonging to only one class of the two?

Comment: You should create a reproducible example (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Beside from that I would guess that you using the `confusionMatrix` function the wrong way. You should go with `confusionMatrix(data=table(pred, truth))` OR `confusionMatrix(pred, truth)`. In the latter function call the data argument is no specified.

Comment: your true label reference, test.labels.gse only has 1 level. Not 2 like your final.classes.xgb.gse. Hence the error.

Comment: Why don you want a confusion matrix for this? Also, if the question is only about how to make `confusionMatrix` work (*i.e.* it's a programming question), consider asking your question to be migrated to StackOverflow.

Comment: Dear Mariodeg, it has no difference with the function confusionMatrix regarding the definition of the arguments. For instance, again if i use confuse.mat.gse18088 <- confusionMatrix(data=final.classes.xgb.gse, reference=test.labels.gse) it returns again the same error !! The notion for using a confusionMatrix is that i would like to compute some statistics regarding the accuracy of my prediction, such as accuracy, specificity etc.

Comment: a bigger example :  test.set.18088 <- t(exprs(eset.gse.18088); dim(test.set.18088)
[1] 53 36 (my genes on the columns and my samples on the rows); test.labels.gse18088 <- factor(eset.gse18088$Status) ; levels(test.labels.gse18088)
[1] "Cancer" & then briefly my classification procedure: xgbTune <- train(y=condition, x=set.2, method="xgbTree",metric="ROC", verbose=FALSE, trControl = xgb_control,tuneGrid=xgb_grid, nthread=4); final.classes.xgb.gse18088 <- predict(xgbTune, newdata = test.set.18088); confuse.mat.gse18088 <- confusionMatrix(data=final.classes.xgb.gse18088, test.labels.gse18088)

Comment: I think this is really a statistical / machine learning question disguised as an R code question.

Answer (score 3):

The `final.classes.xgb.gse18088` variable has two levels, i.e. Cancer and Normal, but `test.labels.gse`  has only one level, Cancer.  `confusionMatrix` is complaining. 
 about that.

These are both factors and a factor can have levels that are not present in the data so just add the Normal level to the levels of `test.labels.gse`:

```
levels(test.labels.gse) <- c("Cancer", "Normal")
```

Now it should produce output.

For example,

```
library(caret)

# test data
final <- factor(c("Cancer", "Cancer", "Cancer", "Cancer", "Normal"))
levels(final)
## [1] "Cancer" "Normal"

test <- factor(c("Cancer", "Cancer", "Cancer", "Cancer", "Cancer"))
levels(test)    
## [1] "Cancer"

# gives expected error
confusionMatrix(final, test)
## Error in confusionMatrix.default(final, test) : 
##   the data cannot have more levels than the reference

# now it produces output
levels(test) <- c("Cancer", "Normal")
confusionMatrix(final, test)
```

giving:

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction Cancer Normal
    Cancer      4      0
    Normal      1      0

               Accuracy : 0.8             
                 95% CI : (0.2836, 0.9949)
    No Information Rate : 1               
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1               

                  Kappa : 0               
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 1               

            Sensitivity : 0.8             
            Specificity :  NA             
         Pos Pred Value :  NA             
         Neg Pred Value :  NA             
             Prevalence : 1.0             
         Detection Rate : 0.8             
   Detection Prevalence : 0.8             
      Balanced Accuracy :  NA             

       'Positive' Class : Cancer
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it only addresses the coding issues. I suspect this is just the surface. (If this Q were really only about R code, it would be off topic here.) Would you be willing to address the conceptual confusion that may lie behind the OP trying to make a confusion matrix in this case? Eg, why does this matrix yield the values listed for standard measures of the model's utility (specificity, pos pred value, etc)? What are the implications of that? Given this, should we be concerned w/ constructing the confusion matrix, or should we be doing something else?

Comment: One can decompose the population into those who truly have Cancer and those who truly do not and since we only have samples from the first we can only compute statistics that involve the first but not the second.  That is what it did as the NA values show.  The sensitivity is the fraction of positives out of those who truly have cancer and the specificity is the fraction of negatives out of those who truly do not so obviously we can still compute the first but not the second.   For example, maybe the \patients were sampled from the files of an oncologist.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't so much hoping you would enlighten me, as much as you might expand your answer to address the conceptual confusion that might have led the OP to this problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Do a table on your predicted variable. I'm going to bet that it only has one level. If so, this means that your model is predicting the same class for all cases in your dataset. Can't be sure why without more info, but it may be that you have terrible separation or severe class imbalance.

Comment: Dear HEINZ, not one of the last cases you have mentioned. I trained my classifier on an expression set with two binary levels-classes: that is normal and cancer samples. As i mention above, one independent dataset i used for external validation, has only cancer samples, not any normal samples--that is the point for the problem above with the confusionMatrix.

Comment: Ah I see. Well no, you can't correct the output of confusionmatrix. Although I've never tried. Maybe you could add an empty level. Alternatively you can compute the matrix yourself, or you can partition your dataset again with a different random seed hoping for >0 cases, but then you're in shaky territory.

Comment: actually i followed your advice on adding the empty level when creating the factor of my true test labels. Of course, then the confusionMatrix works, but of course it return NAs regarding the specificity, as i dont have any " true negatives" regarding the normal samples in the testing dataset